# «Усмехнуться шутке» или «усмехнуться над шуткой»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Подскажите, будьте добры, как правильно: *усмехнуться **шутке*** или *усмехнуться **над шуткой***?

Answer (score 1):

Так вообще редко говорят - "усмехнуться чему-то...". Обычно просто усмехаются, можно усмехнуться при виде чего-то, при мысли о чем-то, чем-то (беззубым ртом). Но вот и в литературе нашла фразу:"Наблюдающие казнь воины усмехаются шутке. Эти люди умеют ценить мужество".
М. И. Веллер, Жестокий.
Так что вполне правильно будет сказать "усмехнуться шутке".